# I can't read data from Transactions

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

When send user data to firestore and login again the system not read this code , he join already to (if) after add data but return failed because I think firestore accept write only is there any solution?

```
if (snapshot.exists()) {
   return snapshot.getString("ID");
}
```

*Code*

```
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Players").document(saveSystem.LoadStringData("LoginType").equals("Facebook") ? "F" + saveSystem.LoadStringData("ID") : "G" + saveSystem.LoadStringData("ID"));
        firebaseFirestore.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
                DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(documentReference);
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    return snapshot.getString("ID");
                } else {
                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("ID", saveSystem.LoadStringData("ID"));
                    return hashMap;
                }
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object aObject) {
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "" + aObject, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
```

Sorry for simple English language.

Comment: What's the problem with the shared code?

Comment: @AlexMamo Good morning , if the system found user on database then read user data only , but the transactions It's not working without writes command